add windows 10 boot option to grub menu
after i installed endevor os, boot menu is not showing windows10 option
sudo os-prober doesnot show any result even after making GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
then tried to add custom entry etc/grub.d/40_custom
as
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(/dev/sda2)  # Modify this to match your Windows partition
    chainloader +1
}

fdisk -l shows
    Disk model: ST1000DM010-2EP1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4E017D50-896E-423C-909A-2D92EDBB31F8

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environm
/dev/sda2      923648    1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1161216  274300927 273139712 130.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   274300928  275773439   1472512   719M Windows recovery environm
/dev/sda6   275777536  695207935 419430400   200G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7   695207936 1532180479 836972544 399.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  1532190720 1721243647 189052928  90.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9  1721243648 1953523711 232280064 110.8G EFI System

now grub menus shows entry named windows10 but is does not open shows some error like not found.

“but is does not open shows some error like not found.” - This statement is difficult to understand so [edit] your question and clarify it, while you do, include the exact error you received

Your list of partitions is a mess, for starters. You have 2 ESPs and 2 Windows recovery partitions. (EndeavourOS is probably installed in another drive, right?) There's really no sane advice that isn't START OVER, i.e., Reinstall Windows (after backing up your personal files there, of course) by deleting ALL partitions in the target drive. Then reinstall EndeavourOS' GRUB only (no need to reinstall the whole system) making sure to NOT create another EFI partition. All bootloaders should go to the same ESP and in any case NEVER have more than one in the same drive.
